# two variables with two different 'range' in the same 'for' loop

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, range

```
letters=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
for (letters_num,a,z) in range(0,26)  range(1,27) , range(26,0,-1):
    print 'letter' ,letters[letters_num] ,'is number' ,a,'from a and number',z,'from z'
```

i want the output to be:

```
letter a is number 1 from a and number 26 from z
letter b is number 2 from a and number 25 from z
letter c is ......
```

what is the right form to put **two variables with two different 'range' in the same 'for' loop??**

```
for x,y in range('range of x') , range ('range of y'):
print x , y
```

i want the **correct form** of  this code , please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use `zip`:

```
for letters_num ,a ,z in zip(range(0,26), range(1,27), range(26,0,-1)):
    print 'letter' ,letters[letters_num] ,'is number' ,a,'from a and number',z,'from z'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
for x, y in zip(range1, range2):
    ....
```

So for example

```
for x, y in zip(range(5), range(6, 11)):
        print(x, y)
0 6
1 7
2 8
3 9
4 10
```